# Extract year from postgres date

Tags: postgresql

If I do the example of documenting works:

```
SELECT EXTRACT(YEAR FROM TIMESTAMP '2001-02-16 20:38:40');
```

But integrating it in my query gives an error, it will be very basic, but I do not know what it is.

```
select
responsable, 
fecha_contratado,
EXTRACT(YEAR FROM TIMESTAMP fecha_contratado) as alta
from rrhh.empleado
where responsable is not null
```

Thank you very much for the help
Postgres 9.3

Comment: What is `fecha_contratado` column type ?

Comment: date (Example : "2016-08-04")

Comment: While I think @OtoShavadze has it solved in his answer, it would be VERY helpful to share the error you are getting in the future.

Comment: @JNevill  Okay. In the next question I will. Greetings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need `TIMESTAMP` keyword in this case, try this:

```
select
responsable, 
fecha_contratado,
EXTRACT(YEAR FROM fecha_contratado) as alta
from rrhh.empleado
where responsable is not null
```